# Any changes on layout, or creating new layout crashes my app. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have an android application which has more than 20 layouts. In recent days if I make any changes in layout (generally id changing, creating new component or layout) crashes my app or changes some layouts by itself. I have a menu and when I click menu icon it shows my custom actionbar layout instead of custom menu layout. Most of time app crashes.

I have tired clean and rebuild project but it doesnt work. I made some search but there is nothing about it. Please help me.

Comment: Check your `MainActivity`, more specifically, a the part where you are trying to set an `OnClickListener` on a relative layout. Maybe you have changed an id or something, but the target `RelativeLayout` is `null`. Posting your activity layout can also be helpful, if you can't find the problem yourself.

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: when I remove page and run it works again there is no problem about RelativeLayout. it crashes everytime when I create new xml page. I think it is about R.java id problem.

Comment: it is not R.id problem. pls post your xml

Comment: You forgot the `findViewById()` call

Comment: Dear my friends There is not a problem about java code. The problem is when I create a new layout page in layout folder without any usage it gives crash. The problem looks like about compiling not coding.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on stackoverflow.

As per below line of your error log you need to bind your **RelativeLayout** which you are using for click listener.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Please check all layout is properly bind.See below example:

```
RelativeLayout youRelativeLayout=findViewById(R.id.yourRelativeLayoutId);
```

Then set **clickListener**.

Comment: There is no problem about my bindings in Java. The problem is I cant add even an empty layout to my layout folder without any usage. I think it is a compiling error

Comment: If you post some code which you are trying, which help us more about problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once check, are you giving old id's to new Views in new Layout. and check all id's you have given in layout files.

Comment: I didnt give any id yet I just added new layout to my loyout folder @Narender

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your Relative Layout as a .setOnClickListener, Use the widgets within the Relative Layout to use methods such as .setOnClickListener.

Comment: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>"   I added this xml layout to my layout folder and it gives same error . When I delete it. My app workes properly.

Comment: It' hard to help you when you don't provide all of the necessary code.

Answer (score 0):

First check it your xml you using Relative layout in this using same as:

```
android:layout_below="@id/LoginTitle"
```

add `+` symbol after `@id/LoginTitle`

When there is no problem you see after check in your java file:
is null because you never initialize it with:
so initialize same as below initialize.

```
Button mAddTaskButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addTaskButton);
```